# Array containing 3 arrays will only print one (python)

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I'm trying to get my array to print all its elements but its only producing one. ive tried commenting out different sections of the 'for row' sections and it shows that they work. it will always just out one. any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
            wA = csv.reader(warehouse_A)
            next(wA, None) ## skips the header
            wB = csv.reader(warehouse_B)
            next(wB, None) ## skips the header
            wC = csv.reader(warehouse_C)
            next(wC, None) ## skips the header
            wD = csv.reader(warehouse_D)
            next(wD, None) ## skips the header


            a_itemno = []           ## empty arrays for the item number of the warehouse to be placed
            a_descripton = []               ## empty arrays for the item descripton of the warehouse to be placed
            a_value = []            ## empty arrays for the item value of the warehouse to be placed

            b_itemno = []           
            b_descripton = []               
            b_value = []            

            c_itemno = []           
            c_descripton = []               
            c_value = []            

            d_itemno = []           
            d_descripton = []               
            d_value = []            


            for row in wA:   ## places the 1st row on the spreadsheets into a new array
            a_itemno.append(row[0])

            for row in wB:
            b_itemno.append(row[0])

            for row in wC:
            c_itemno.append(row[0])

            for row in wD:
            d_itemno.append(row[0])


            for row in wA:   ## places the 2rd row on the spreadsheets into a new array
            a_descripton.append(row[1])

            for row in wB:
            b_descripton.append(row[1])

            for row in wC:
            c_descripton.append(row[1])

            for row in wD:
            d_descripton.append(row[1])


            for row in wA:   ## places the 3rd row on the spreadsheets into a new array
            a_value.append(row[2])

            for row in wB:
            b_value.append(row[2])

            for row in wC:
            c_value.append(row[2])

            for row in wD:
            d_value.append(row[2])


            new_wA = [[a_itemno], [a_descripton], [a_value]] ## new array that only prints one element

            print (new_wA)
```

The output im looking for would be:
[[[blah, blah, blah,], [blah, blah, blah], [blah,blah, blah]],[[blah, blah, blah,], [blah, blah, blah], [blah,blah, blah]],[[blah, blah, blah,], [blah, blah, blah], [blah,blah, blah]]]

instead all im getting is:
[[[blah, blah, blah,], [blah, blah, blah], [blah,blah, blah]],[[]], [[]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through the rows of `csv.reader`, you're reading right through the whole file, without rewinding. Unfortunately, you can't read through the same open file twice with `csv.reader` by using two separate for loops that loop through the whole file.

To read through the rows of `csv.reader` twice, you'll want to store the rows in a separate variable like this:

```
wA = csv.reader("warehouse_A")
wA_list = list(wA)

for row in wA_list:
    a_itemno.append(row[0])
for row in wA_list:
    a_value.append(row[2])
```

Alternatively, if your file is too big to be loaded into memory, consider amending the logic and doing everything you need in one pass, for example:

```
for row in wA:
    a_itemno.append(row[0])
    a.descripton.append(row[1])
    a_value.append(row[2])
```

Comment: Great, Thank you!